# Angular i18n with two different links

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I have an angular app with implemented i18n for choosing language depends on customer will. Now I want to set up a footer with a link which will be redirected to a differing site depends on language e.g.
link1="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)"
link2="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular"
, so I will have one alias which will be redirected to different sites depends on the chosen language.

I tried to use angular pipes but I have no idea how to set up.

```
<a href="'" class="footer__link">{{'footer.angular' | translate}}</a>
```

Comment: what library are you using ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?I installed i18n npm package in this project and I tried to use pipes to achive that what i describe. Maybe there is another way to implemented that.

Comment: You can try using [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core). I don't know if there is a native Angular one, but this one is great.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So I have installed ngx-translate to project set up service, etc. To got different value key depends on language I use property binding in Angular. Angular grabbing property from i18n .json and setting my variable.

```
footer.angular.link="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework
```

and

```
<a [href]="'footer.angular.link' | translate" class="footer__link">{{'footer.angular' | translate}}</a>
```

It's quite easy solution but maybe someone will have better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to provide different links depending on the locale language to be translated.

The solution to make it work was the following:

1. In the `component.ts` file add all the links URL as variables:

   ```
   link1 = localize$`https://en.example-link1.com`;
   ```

2. Then add this variables to the `component.html` file using property binding:

   ```html
   <a [href]="link1"> my link </a>
   ```
3. In the translation file I get the source with link1 and just have to provide link2 as a target when the page is translated.

   ```html
   <source>
     link1 = localize$`https://en.example-link1.com`;
   </source>

   <target>
     link2 = localize$`https://de.example-link2.com`;
   </target>
   ```